# sql lite query, why its returning everything

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm using this query

> query = "SELECT * FROM ri UNION SELECT * FROM pj UNION SELECT * FROM
>   td UNION SELECT * FROM cert UNION SELECT * FROM outros WHERE grupo =
>   'Grupo 1'";

I tried grupo like 'Grupo 1', but dont worked too

why its returning everything from column grupo, i want only the results that match grupo 1

!!

and another append question, how to make a copy of the file.db + date... im planing to do a backup of a file everyday doing a copy of it in another folder with the date of the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `grupo` is in each table then you need a WHERE clause on each SELECT. Right now the only query that is being filtered is `SELECT * FROM outros`.

Here is some revise code. BTQ: please don't use `SELECT *` in real life....

```
SELECT * 
FROM ri 
WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM pj 
WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM td 
WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM cert 
WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM outros 
WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
```

Comment: You could use a subquery too with one `WHERE` at the end; equally hideous, though.

Comment: Jason - Agreed, but I wanted the OP to explicitly understand that the WHERE clasue has to apply ot all the SELECTS.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` operator has a higher precedence than `UNION`. Your query is actually:

```
SELECT * FROM ri 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM pj 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM td 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM cert 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM outros WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
```

The `WHERE` clause only applies to the final `SELECT * FROM outros`. You will either need to add that `WHERE` to every subquery that has a `grupo` column (you didn't specify which so I'll assume all):

```
SELECT * FROM ri WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
UNION 
SELECT * FROM pj WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
UNION 
SELECT * FROM td WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
UNION 
SELECT * FROM cert WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
UNION 
SELECT * FROM outros WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
```

Or you can use a subquery like this (not tested, syntax might be off, sorry):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM ri 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM pj 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM td 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM cert 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM outros 
)
WHERE grupo = 'Grupo 1'
```

By the way, you probably don't want to use `*` in `UNION` selects, since if one of the tables schema changes, the query will fail. It is better, if possible, to explicitly select all of the columns.